# Carousel web component for polymer 3

Tags: polymer-3.x

I want to use a carousel web component and i can only find one from older versions [like](https://github.com/Link2Twenty/l2t-paper-slider) for **polymer 2**
how do i install it as bower is not supported in **polymer 3**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the polymer-modulizer tool to convert a Polymer 2 component into a Polymer 3 component:

https://github.com/Polymer/tools/tree/master/packages/modulizer